# Sorting a pandas dataframe by a column

Tags: python, pandas

I retrieved a csv file from the IMDB database. I imported this file with `titles = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('titles.csv', index_col=None)`.
I have tried many `sort/order` commands on my ipython notebook, but all of them are throwing errors.

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-bb0d78f2f73d> in <module>()
----> 1 sort(titles[titles.title== 'Hamlet'])

NameError: name 'sort' is not defined
```

I tried the following to sort the year series in my dataframe, consisting of year and title.

```
order(titles$title) 
sort(titles[titles.title== 'Hamlet'])
titles['year'].sort()
titles['year].order()
order(titles.year)
titles.sort('year')
titles.order('year')
```

Comment: Need `titles['year'].sort_values()`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: It works but gives me only values of 'year' , need 'title' values too.

Comment: need `titles.sort_values('year')`

Comment: Thanks jezrael , this works. How do we use order() ?

Comment: Order is too old, [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-sorting-api), not used yet.